# Mv files listed in txt file up a directory

Tags: bash, python

This is my first time asking a question :)
I am new to bash scripting but pretty good with python. I have a directory with a bunch of files, and I have a text file that contains a subset of file names within the directory. I am trying to write a script that will read that txt file, select the files that are listed in the txt file from the directory, and move them up a directory.

It may sound simple enough but there are hundreds of them so I am trying to automate! Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @RomeoNinov not much of anything yet... bash syntax is so confusing to me!

Comment: @steeldriver Thankyou! looking at it now!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the list contains full filenames and the files are in the same folder as the list, here is a command:

```
while IFS= read -r file; do mv "$file" ../"$file"; done < listoffiles.txt
```

- `while ...; do ...; done` cycle operators
- `read file` declare variable `file`
- `mv` move
- `$file ../$file` source - destination. The `..` stands for 'one level higher directory' (e.g. `/home/user/documents` is your current directory, `/home/user` will be your `..`
- `listoffiles.txt` your file that contains the list.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much, this really helps me to understand what is happening :)